# How do I check whether a module is installed in Python, and install it if needed?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, python

In terminal, after I start Python, how will I know what are the modules present in python?
Suppose I need to learn the modules NumPy and SciPy.

- How will I install it if it is not installed?
- How will I know if it is already installed?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**How to know if a python module is installed or not in the system:** You can do a very easy test in terminal,

```
$ python -c "import math"
$ echo $?
0                                # math module exists in system

$ python -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
$ echo $?
1                                # numpy module does not exist in system
```

#### How will I install it if it is not installed

You can install specific module by downloading respective packages from repository, for example you can [install `scipy`](https://askubuntu.com/a/588512/127327) as,

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy ## for Python2
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy ## for Python3
```

**Alternately** You can also install a python module using `python-pip` as suggested by Zack Titan in the [comment below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588390/how-do-i-check-whether-a-module-is-installed-or-not-in-python#comment816847_588392), To install `numpy` you can use

```
pip install numpy
```

**Warning:** It is highly recommended to install python-modules using official Ubuntu repository only and not to use the `pip` method as **superuser**(i.e., as `root` or using `sudo`). In some cases it may leave your system unusable by breaking system python.

[**How to install packages using `pip` into local virtual environment.**](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html)

Comment: Like in your answer math module exists and  for numby the traceback didnt appear and for echo $? output was 0, Does it mean numpy is also present in my system?

Comment: yes, it is there in your system.

Comment: In case you don't have the module numpy how will you import it? When we do the coding we call the import statement by  from numpy import *, will it install the module ? If not how will we install a new module?

Comment: If you get error on calling a module like above that means it is not installed in your system. No, it will not install the module.

Comment: It will be a septate question how to install a module. Need different packages for different module. For example to install `vpython` you need to install it as `sudo apt-get install python-visual libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev`

Comment: You can also use pip to install modules. But first, pip needs to be installed first. `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and then to install modules, just type `pip install numpy`

Comment: @ZackTitan Current versions of python come with `pip` already installed, so you can do `python -m pip install` without having to install `pip` as an external program.

Comment: @Bakuriu Oh, didn't knew it. When I install it, i had to install pip through easy_install and distribute. That's done on windows I think. But Linux is much simpler. Thanks for your info.

Comment: @ZackTitan: pip is included with python on Windows too (since Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.4). Run `python -m ensurepip`, to make sure `pip` is installed there.

Comment: don't use `sudo pip`; it may break system python. Use apt-get to install packages for system python. You could use `pip  --user` option or virtualenv to install Python packages for yourself.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I agree with your opinion, and added the warning.

Comment: @souravc: the point is to avoid `sudo`, not `pip`. I use `pip` all the time to install various packages into local virtual environments.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I mentioned that only. Please read the last line "if run as superuser" i.e., as `root` or using `sudo`.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that you can find out what has been installed in a given environment by using pip with `pip list` command.

Comment: In Windows use `python -c "import math"` then `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`.

Answer (score 33):

In case we do not want to unwantedly import a module in question (which would happen in  a `try` statement) we can make use of `sys.modules` to test modules that are installed **and** were imported before.

In the python shell issue:

```
>>> import sys
```

Then test for installed modules:

```
>>> 'numpy' in sys.modules
True
>>> 'scipy' in sys.modules
False
```

Note that only those modules that were imported before give `True` on this test, all other modules (even if installed) result in `False.`

Another alternative to `try` an `import` statement in the python console is calling the inbuilt `help()` function. This will not give a documentation for non-installed modules, e.g.

```
>>> help('scipy')
no Python documentation found for 'scipy'
```

The output of very long help documents of installed modules can be interrupted with <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Now to install missing modules it is recommended to use the **Ubuntu package management** (and not the Python pip way) because we need root access and also to prevent messing up our heavily Python-dependend system. For the module in question this would e.g. be:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy ## for Python2
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy ## for Python3
```

After installation we then can add them to the `sys.modules` dictionary by importing them once.

Comment: I think this is most Pythonic answer....

Comment: The first part of this is wrong: `sys.modules` only contains modules that have *already been imported*, so it is not a reliable way to test whether a module has been installed. The most reliable test is to use a `try/except` and trap the `ImportError`, as several others have already suggested.

Comment: @ekhumoro - thanks, I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: It still seems not sufficiently clear. Given that the question is asking how to find out if a module is _installed_ (not _imported_), `sys.modules` is entirely irrelevant and I think any mention of it is misleading. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: `sys.modules` is not any help here.

Comment: What's wrong with importing a module just for checking? Is it really that costly to import?

Answer (score 25):

Another way is the [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) module. Works with both Python 2 & 3:

```
python -c 'import pkgutil; print(1 if pkgutil.find_loader("module") else 0)'
```

You need to replace `module` with the name of your module, example:

```
$ python -c 'import pkgutil; print(1 if pkgutil.find_loader("math") else 0)'
1
```

Comment: I saw you undid some of my changes; `print()` will also work fine in Python 2; It's treated as a the group-with-parens syntax, and doesn't have any side effects. Only when you want to add multiple items (as in `print('a', 'b')` it will be treated as a `tuple`, in which you do need the `from __future__ import print_function`, but that's not applicable in this case, you can just write forward-compatible code by adding the parens (I tested my changes in Python 2 and 3).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Thanks for pointing out. I rollback to the old version.

Comment: This is a great answer. I added a derivative answer that returns an exit/status code (for shell script flow control) and takes the module name as a command line argument. https://askubuntu.com/a/891384/146273

Comment: That worked! - Just change to [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) so it can be used in shell context: `python -c 'import pkgutil; exit(0 if pkgutil.find_loader("math") else 2)'`

Answer (score 19):

I know the OP originally asked for a solution after starting Python, but outside of python I use `pip`. On ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install python-pip`, if it's not already installed.

Then to see what third party modules are available, just run:

```
pip freeze
```

Or even

```
pip list
```

And both will show you all modules installed and their versions.

If the module you're looking for is not installed, most of the time you can easily install it with pip:

```
pip install <module-name>
```

If you're not sure of whether a module exists or what its PyPI name is, use `pip search`:

```
pip search <keyword>
```

It appears that `pip search` no longer functions. (See @AJM's comment below). I tend to use [Pypi's search directly](https://pypi.org/search/)

Comment: Also, `pip show <module-name>` will show whether a package is installed, e.g. `pip show numpy`.

Comment: `pip search` no longer works: PyPI's XMLRPC API has been disabled. There's information on why this decision was made at https://www.theregister.com/2021/05/25/pypi_search_error/ - but that article was written when the disablement was only temporary. An email announcement was sent out in January making it permanent.

Comment: Thanks @AJM. Updated

Answer (score 13):

You could put the code inside `try`, `except` block.

```
$ python3 -c "\
try:
    import cow  
    print('\nModule was installed')
except ImportError:
    print('\nThere was no such module installed')"

There was no such module installed
```

---

```
$ python3 -c "\
try:
    import regex
    print('\nModule was installed')
except ImportError:
    print('\nThere was no such module installed')"

Module was installed
```

Answer (score 9):

To provide another answer, for completion's sake:

You can (ab)use the `-m` option. From Python's manpage:

```
   -m module-name
          Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the  correspond‐
          ing .py file as a script.
```

Which will give us:

```
$ python2 -m numpy
/sbin/python2: No module named numpy.__main__; 'numpy' is a package and cannot be directly executed

$ python2 -m math
/sbin/python2: No code object available for math
```

But for non-existent modules, it will give us:

```
$ python2 -m doesnt_exist
/sbin/python2: No module named doesnt_exist
```

We could use `grep` to match for this:

```
$ python2 -m doesnt_exist |& grep -q 'No module named' && echo 'Nope' || echo 'Yup'
Nope

$ python2 -m math |& grep -q 'No module named' && echo 'Nope' || echo 'Yup'
Yup
```

This is slightly hack-ish, and not what `-m` was intended for; but it is the
method that requires the least typing if you want a quick test :-)

Comment: `grep -q` makes redirection to null unnecessary.

Comment: @muru Yikes! I have typed a lot of useless redirects to `/dev/null` over the years :-/

Answer (score 6):

I wrote an example in Python:

```
import pip
import sys
from bigml.api import BigML


if not 'bigml' in sys.modules.keys():
    pip.main(['install', 'bigml'])
```

Answer (score 5):

## Shell oneliner check (useful for provisioning)

I found that in order to make my infrastructure provisioning** idempotent, I need to be able to check for a package from the shell in a oneliner. I built on @cuonglm's answer. I had to reverse the `1` and `0` because I'm producing an exit status rather than printing a string.

```
python -c "import sys, pkgutil; sys.exit(0 if pkgutil.find_loader(sys.argv[1]) else 1)" pymongo
```

You could replace the `sys.argv[1]` with the single quoted name of your package, but for my provisioning scripts I like the readability of having it at the end.

```
python -c "import sys, pkgutil; sys.exit(0 if pkgutil.find_loader('pymongo') else 1)"
```

** I realize that [chef](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/poise-python), [puppet](https://github.com/stankevich/puppet-python), and [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html) all have plugins for managing python packages, but you may find yourself in a situation like me where you are using an outdated version and don't want to use deprecated plugins.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use `pydoc modules`, which can be filtered with `grep` to find a specific module. The output is displayed in columnated format. The only disadvantage of this approach is that it also will include python files in the current working directory. Nonetheless,I use it myself most of the time and it's one of the highly cited approaches on this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/739993/3701431

Answer (score 1):

From the Ubuntu Shell, by default bash, as simple as

```
pip list | grep <package-name-Case-Matters>
```

Examples

```
pip list | grep pywinrm

pip list | grep numpy
```

And, if you have doubts about the case (although I think all the package names are always lowercase):

```
pip list | grep [Nn]um[Pp]y  # it works with numpy, Numpy, numPy, and NumPy
```

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this, `pip show ...` seems to be the easiest way:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/

But it is silent (ie. returns nothing) when the package is not installed.

Comment: I have pip 21.2.4 and pip show returns 0 when package exists and 1 when it does not. Also you get a nice warning in the stdout if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

pymodules=(
    requests
    termcolor
)

for module in "${pymodules[@]}"; do
    if python3 -c "import pkgutil; exit(1 if pkgutil.find_loader(\"$module\") else 0)"; then
        pip3 install --user "$module"
    fi
done
```

It will install any module thats missing from the `pymodules` array.

Using `--user` makes pip install packages in your home directory instead of a system directory like `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/`, this is useful as it doesn't require any special privileges and keeps your system installation clean.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I come up with:

```
if [[ ! $(pip list|grep "numpy") ]]; then
    pip install numpy
fi
```

It will check if numpy has been installed on your system, if not, it will install numpy using pip.

Answer (score 0):

This code will check if the modules in the list are installed or not. If a module is not yet installed, it will install it.

```
import sys
modules=['pandas','numpy'] # modules to install
for module in modules:
    if module in sys.modules:
        print('module: '+module+' already installed')
    else:
        print('install module: '+module)
        !pip install module
```

Answer (score 0):

to install or update pip packages (if they are not installed or up to date) from a terminal or shell script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# install or update pip and yq if they are not installed or up to date
for pkg in pip yq; do
  pip list --uptodate | grep "${pkg} " || pip install --upgrade ${pkg}
done
```